# Wpf Infragistics xamDataGrid - convert nested data / Grouped data into html format

Tags: wpf, infragistics

Scenario :

1) Created a dataset of 3 datatables , added relationship between fields

2) Binding data with xamDataGrid done, it is showing nested / grouped data on the grid.

3) Converted the nested/grouped data to excel file using infragistics inbuild excel functionality.

4-> Now want to export the same data to pdf format(PROBLEM). For that i have to create a html file with nested structure and then using a 3rd party tool i can convert it (html to pdf file). PROBLEM is that i am not able to get the nested structure of the data / grouped data from the grid . 
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

You could export the XamDataGrid to XPS and then convert that XPS to PDF.

The following will help with exporting to XPS:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/wpf/articles/printing-the-xamdatagrid-with-infragistics-reports.aspx

The following may be able to be used to convert the XPS to PDF:
http://nixps.com/library.html

Note I haven't tested the NiXPS library.